# Issue in get data. Bind the get data name as label and user_Id as value in multiselect dropdown using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not able to bind the get data value in dropdown it shows [object Object] but it gets values and label in console when I select one list in dropdown. I tried the JSON.Stringify() also but it didn't work. I share my code.

```
 export default class AddSchedule extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
                        trainerlist:[]
        }
    }
GetTrainers = async (department) => {
        this.GetMembers(department);
        let url = `https://ABCDEFGH/XYZ?Department=${department}&TrainerInfo=${1}`;
        let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        const accessToken = user;
        const reqData = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Request-Headers"
            },
        })
        const resData = await reqData.json();
       const obj = {}
         for (let i = 0; i < resData.length; i++) {
        this.state.trainerDrop.push({ Id: resData[i].user_Id, label: resData[i].label });
         } 
        this.setState({ trainerlist: resData })
        console.log("trainerlist: ", this.state.trainerlist);
        console.log("TrainersDetails", resData);
    }

 render() {
        const { trainerlist} = this.state;
      return(

<div>
                                                                                        <Multiselect className="effect-16" showArrow
                                                                                          options={(trainerlist.map(item => ({
                                                                                             label: (item.label),
                                                                                            value: (item.user_Id)
                                                                                          })))}
                                                                                        getSelectedItems={trainerDrop}
                                                                                        isObject={false}
                                                                                        name="TrainerName"
                                                                                        onSelect={this.handleMultiselectChange}
                                                                                       />

</div>

)}
```

[It shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJzh.png)[image: but it takes in console]

Share your Knowledge. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share how you are rendering `trainerlist`